# Angular 9 access JSON object values

Tags: angular

I'm trying to convert object to JSON in HTML and then access a value:
{{obj | json}[id]}.

Can this be done in HTML? What's the correct way to do this inline HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{{ obj.id | json }}
```

or just

```
{{ obj.id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is an object you can use in HTML as `{{obj.id | json}}`

I made a demo for your case https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-id